# Do spin_lock and spin_unlock hurt performance of an SMP kernel on a single-cpu machine?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, spinlock

On my Ubuntu machine, default kernel image which is running is built for smp (`CONFIG_SMP=y`). But this machine has only 1 cpu.

On uni-processor kernel, unlike smp kernel, `spin_lock/unlock` are null functions.
So how does `spin_lock()` and `spin_unlock()` behave in this setup?

Is there any performance impact due to such smp specific code?

Comment: I agree. This definitely sounds super-user-ish to me.

Comment: Edited the question from programming perspective !!!

Comment: Can we reopen it? I need an answer for this one !!!

Comment: What the ...!! this IS related to programming. Any kernel programmer will agree with me. This is sad :(

Comment: I totally object to the closed decision! How more software related can one get with questions about using a software method within the Linux Kernel API!??? @Michael @Harper @Pablo @Jerry @Dirk @Brian

Comment: @IanVaughan: You're right, the question in its current form is on topic. Check the revision history to see why it was closed.

Comment: @IanVaughan: As a side note, only the first @-mention in a comment works, and you can't @-mention people who closed a question. Fortunately I'm now a moderator (I wasn't when I made that earlier comment), so I can reopen it myself.

Answer (score 3):

Current Linux kernels contain a patch that you can google for with the terms "SMP alternatives". In short, during boot, if the kernel detects that it's running on a uniprocessor machines, the spinlock functions are hot-patched with no-ops.

Answer (score 0):

Yes (And probably no).

Yes: 
A. The spin lock/unlock will run the actual code of the locking and unlocking because when you compile it the compiler doesn't know if you going to run it on a machine with one or more CPUs.
B. Although you have one CPU you may still want to use it if you using threads.

Probably no:
I'm guessing you asking because you don't use threads for the part you need to lock, and you only have one CPU. In that case the spin lock should never get into spin. So the performance overhead is negligible.